# Replace values in cell with DAX coding in Power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have my data(file name - Data) which I have imported in power bi with a column named values

| values |
| --- |
| ext |
| int |
| safety_int |
|  |
| outside_training |
| gap_fill_int |
|  |

so it is a large data, and it contains more than 2k categories , what I want is, to create a new column in power bi where blanks should be replaced with target_emp, and all other values(ext,int,gap_filling_int etc.) should be replaced with non_target_emp.
Please help me to do that in power bi.

Answer (score 1):

In powerbi transform ->

Add Column:

```
if Text.Trim([category]) = "" then "target_emp" else "non_target_emp"
```

[image]

Comment: This should be the preferred solution since it both avoids a calculated column in DAX (increased efficiency) and takes care to trim the value before comparing it with an empty string (increased accuracy).

Answer (score 0):

You could add a conditional column in the data model (sorry that I dont have an English screenshot for this):

1. Add column
2. Select conditional column
3. Add criteria to selection

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#1 DAX

```
calculatedColumn= SWITCH(TRUE(), Data[Column1]=BLANK(),"target_emp", "non_target_emp")
```

[image: Solution]

#2 using PBI's binning

go to report view->click on the table->column name-> New Group
[image: Solution2]

[image: Solution3]